# I'm parsing an RSS feed without a pubDate, is there any other way(s) to figure out when an item was published?

Tags: java, android, rss

So, as the title says, I'd like to know if anyone knows of any alternatives to using pubDate to figure out when something was posted.  I'm just pulling XML from an RSS feed on a website into my app, when I realized that there weren't any dates on any of the articles... BUT, I tried parsing the feed in Feedly, and it figures out the correct day of the publication, so I'm assuming that there IS in fact some way to do this.

Anyone have any ideas?

Edit: while looking at the source code of [ViennaRSS](https://github.com/ViennaRSS/vienna-rss/blob/master/src/RichXMLParser.m#L779-L792) I see that they use a trick by setting each successive article to be one second later than the last, to make sure that at least the articles show up in the right order, but I don't have that problem as mine are already parsed and shown in order.  At first I got excited...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no pubDate is included I would use the timestamp when an item is discovered in the feed. If the time between feed updates isn't too large the date will probably be OK.

Comment: That's not going to work, this feed gets updates maybe a couple times a month, and I want to show the dates of the old ones too... they're scientific studies so an accurate date is usually important.

Comment: When checking for items every hour the date is almost always correct. Only when an item is published just before midnight and the next check is after midnight it can be 1 day off. If that's not good enough, perhaps you can determine the date from the article itself. If you can find a fixed place in the page source with the publication date, retrieve the page using the URL of the RSS item and parse the page for the part containing the date.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your answer originally then, but using that method couldn't get me a date for anything older than the next article that comes out (and all after that), right?

Comment: You have to build you own mechanism to detect new items in the feed and store them, including their publication date. Then each time after retrieving the feed compare the feed contents with the items you stored.